# Why doesn't this Rails 3 AREL line work after upgrade to Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel

The line in question is:

```
product_properties.includes(:property).where("properties.name = 'Label Description'").first
```

It exists in a "Product" model, which has_many :product_properties. The SQL is generating, but throwing a MySQL error because it is trying to SELECT a blank column:

```
SELECT  `product_properties`.`` AS t0_r0, `product_properties`.`id` AS t0_r1, ...
```

How can I troubleshoot what is causing that SELECT of a blank row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The clue is looking at the second column in the SELECT statement above. It is "id". That's normally the first column.

The "id" in this particular table was not set as a primary key, so the table had no primary key. Apparently there are AREL changes in 3.1 that cause Rails to look for a primary key, and to return blank when one is not found. That caused the problem. I don't know if that is a Rails bug or not.

Comment: I would submit a ticket for this behaviour if you're not sure. They'll close it if it's expected behaviour. Better to have a bug closed than for one to go unreported and for other people to hit this problem.